# ask the user for the maximum number to print out to and then print each multiple of the base number starting from the base to the maximum

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Please enter the max number:");
int max = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Please enter the base:");
int base = input.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i <= max; max % base == 0;) {
    System.out.println("Number is " + i);
}
```

How do I get it to print the multiples of a number?

Comment: You'll need some kind of `if` statement _inside_ the `for` loop.  Also, the third section of the parenthesised part of the `for` loop is wrong - it should probably be something like `i++` to increment `i` for the next iteration.

Comment: Instead of `i++`, you may want to try `i += base` (in the 3rd part of the for loop)

Comment: [For loop syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `Diabolus` already has a solution, here's the same using a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = base; i <= max; i++)
{
    if(i % base == 0)
        System.out.println("Number is - " + i);
}
```

The number iterates from the base to the maximum number (if you start from zero, `0` too will be printed, as it divides completely by any number)

**Note** that even the base number will be printed. If you wish to avoid this, set `i = base` to `i = base + 1`.

Comment: thank you, I had something similar to that at first but due to syntax it wasn't working. Helped alot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have fully understood your question. However, I believe this is the solution you were looking for:

```
int currentMultiple = 0;

int step = 1;
do {
    currentMultiple = (base * step);
    System.out.println(currentMultiple);
    step += 1;
} while ( currentMultiple <= max );
```

You're needing a while or do while loop for this problem. Since you are unaware of when the current multiple is going to exceed the input.

Let me know if this is what you needed!

Comment: thanks i  understood the code but for my lab it wanted it in a for loop